# Expression quasiquoter for an AST where one constructor produces a monadic computation?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

In a very simplified sense, I have something like the following:

```
type Runtime a = {- More or less a StateT on top of an Either monad -}

-- The list of strings in Fn is a bunch of parameter names, the values of
-- which are pushed into the state of the runtime before executing the actual
-- function expr
data Expr = Num Int
          | Str T.Text
          | Fn [T.Text] (Runtime Expr)
          | {- Bunch of other constructors -}

eval :: Expr -> Runtime Expr
parseExp :: Parser Expr
```

Now, I've never used Template Haskell for anything before I decided it'd be convenient to have a quasi quoter for my toy language, so I admit I might be missing something obvious.

But in any case, I started fiddling around a bit with it, followed some tutorials etc. and basically found that everything except how to deal with the `Fn` constructor was easy.

During my information foragings on the web, I found two general ways people wrote the expression quoter:

- Making their `Expr` data type an instance of TH:s `Lift` and simply  [| quote |] the expression that the parse resulted in
- Deriving `Data` and `Typeable` for their equivalent of `Expr`, and then apply `dataToExpQ` on the same parser result

In both cases, I ran into complications with the `Runtime Expr`. For the first case, the problem was that I couldn't figure out how to implement:

```
instance Lift Expr where
  lift (Fn ps e) = [| Fn ps ...? |]
```

(I did manage to implement the instance for Data.Text on my own though).

I suppose the *real* issue is that I simply don't know TH well enough yet, but no amount of tutorials or exmaples so far has helped me get anywhere with this.

In the second case, the issue was that for `Expr` to be an instance of `Data`, there also needs to be an

```
instance Data (StateT (...) (Either ...) Expr) where
  -- Something
```

My question then, is whether there's an easy way to do this? Or perhaps I should rethink how the functions of my toy language work?

If the latter, any recommendations on how to get equivalent functionality without running them inside a monad? That does seem the intuitive solution, after all, as the run-time environment of the language requires state and error handling (which is what I use `Either` for).

Comment: Could you elaborate on the complications you ran into, please.

Comment: Tried to clarify the complications a bit. Problem is, I pretty much don't know where to even begin with either implementation, so I can't really elaborate much more--this is how far I've gotten so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Expr` data type doesn't need to be liftable in order for you to build a quasiquoter for it, and in this case, it's impossible to implement a `Lift` instance. The reason is that you can't "look inside" the `Runtime Expr` value, since a `StateT` values are essentially functions and there's no generic way to find out what a function does.

What you need to do is to construct the AST that builds up the `Expr` "by hand", i.e. without using the [| |]-quoters (or to be more specific, you can use the [| |]-quotes to help you build the AST, but you can't quote the `Expr` data directly).

So in essence, you need a parser of type

```
parseExpQ :: Parser ExpQ
```

which produces the [Exp](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/latest/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#t%3aExp) that represents the Haskell code needed to build the `Expr`. For the `Fn` constructor, you'd need to either build a do-block using the `DoE`-constructor or a bind chain using `InfixE` and `>>=`.

If this sounds too complicated, your other option is to represent the function body as an expression (or a list of statements, depending on the semantics of your toy language). I.e.

```
data Expr = Num Int
          | Str T.Text
          | Fn [T.Text] [Statement]
```

And define the `Statement` type so that it can be interpreted to produce the same effects that you previously used `StateT Either` for.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it. A separate issue I ran into though:
in ghci, running anything like [toy| someExpr |] results in "parse error on input `|]'", even though I've set it up to deal with TH (runQ [| whatever |] works as expected, for instance). Any idea?

Comment: You need `{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}` at the top or your file or -XQuasiQuotes as a compiler option.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't notice you said GHCi. In GHCi you can enable language extensions by: `:set -XQuasiQuotes`

Comment: Got it. I already had the language pragma, but I had to set it in ghci as well anyway.